# reason to put an array within a json in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
data = {
    "address": [
        {
            "address1": "14 new york"
        },
        {
            "address2": "tower B"
        },
        {
            "postcode": 4577
        }
    ]
}
```

above is a valid json, and it's working if I do `data.address[0].address1` to retrieve the `14 new york`. But I'm thinking whether it's a correct way to structure the json to be like that, because one user can only have 1 address, why not letting me access it using `address.address1`?

I'm asking this wondering why the database guy put an array within the address object.

Comment: *"above is a valid json"* --- No there is not. There is a Javascritp object literal. If it was JSON it would be a **string**.

Comment: this way makes it easy to add information to the address while it's not needed to change the code. (if you output the data in a loop)

Comment: @MörreNoseshine what is the different? you know the context of this question right?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `[0]` because you put an array in 'address'. I suggest you to modify your data structure this way :

```
data = {
"address": 
    {
        "address1": "14 new york",
        "address2": "tower B",
        "postcode": 4577
    }
}
```

So you can use `data.address.address1`.

EDIT: **WHY** the database guy did this ? I don't see any valid reason, I think it is a mistake

Comment: i think the question was WHY and not HOW ;)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: probably laziness.

Without seeing code it keeps guess work. (don't even know what language the backend is written in)

But probably something like `SELECT 'address1', 'address2', ... FROM adresses WHERE ...'`  is executed. Depending on the select statement the db returns 1 or more records.. by default most backend languages interpret this in an array.. (because it can have 0, 1 or more records) => the backend developer could have made it easier by mapping it, selecting the first.

Most ORM frameworks are smart enough to do this for you if you tell it the object has only 1 (one to one or many to one relationship)

- [(Java) Hybernate example of one to one](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-1.html)
- [(Java) Hybernate example of one to many](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-1.html)
- [(.NET) Entity Framework example of one to one](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)